# Symfony2 and doctrine wants "drifes" instead "drives"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I got this error while submit a form.

[image: Exception: Neither the property "drives" nor one of the methods "addDrife()", "setDrives()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User".]

But everything is correctly in the entities.
I have no errors in the mapping, everything is valid.

If i search "drife" the IntelliJ IDEA said: **no matches**.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var Drive[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Drive", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
private $drives;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->drives = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addDrive(Drive $drive)
{
    $drive->setUser($this);
    $this->drives[] = $drive;

    return $this;
}

public function removeDrive(Drive $drive)
{
    $drive->setUser();
    $this->drives->removeElement($drive);
}

public function getDrives()
{
    return $this->drives;
}
```

Comment: The controller issnt important. Look at the cookbook controller. The funny thing is that there is no "drife" in the whole projekt. The form contains no drife, too :/

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the [doctrine/inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector) which is responsable for the singular/plural forms of words

Comment: Debflav how it could be a typo error if there is no drife :/ A replace of v to f issnt there, too. :(

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache ? That is a weird error, you should try to rename the property to something else and see how it handles that.

Comment: I deleted the app/cache directory completly. Not working. If i renamed the functions it works. But "getDrives" works, too. addDrife is the same as addDrive >.> edit: updating db schema doesnt works, too.

Comment: @debflav i think acrobat is right ^^

Comment: Yes @acrobat is right: http://www.magmadigital.co.uk/2014/symfony-association-names/

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this.

I should read more ...

```
/**
 * Set drives
 *
 * @param Drive[] $drives
 * @return User $this
 */
public function setDrives($drives)
{
    foreach($this->drives as $drive)
    {
        $this->removeDrive($drive);
    }
    foreach($drives as $drive)
    {
        $this->addDrive($drive);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Or rename it to "HardDrives".

The problem is the StringUtil.

```
/vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\StringUtil.php:85

// hooves (hoof), dwarves (dwarf), elves (elf), leaves (leaf), caves (cave), staves (staff)
array('sev', 3, true, true, array('f', 've', 'ff')),
```

So dri -> ves <- would be dri -> fes <-.

Comment: hmm but i think add and remove functions would be better. The problem is this: /vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\StringUtil.php:85

Replace "ves" with "f", "ve" or "ff" ... Thats the problem!